# Removing last 9 characters from a string and then reformatting the remaining date characters

Tags: javascript, date

My question has 2 parts. First I would like to remove the last 9 characters from a generated string using jQuery eg

2011-04-04T15:05:54

which would then leave the date remaining. I know to use the .substring function.
After the time is removed I need to reformat the date into this format

08.04.11 (for eg)

I am learning how to write jQuery and would appreciate any help with this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you do with pure javascript, jQuery is not needed.

```
var d1=new Date();
d1.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');       //returns "2009-06-29"
d1.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy')  //returns "Monday, June 29,2009"
```

Another example to fit your case:

```
var d1=new Date();
d1.toString('dd.MM.yy');       //returns "08.04.11"
```

More:

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: +1 for promoting a javascript solution. jQuery is not required to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. If I can just clarify how I would use your code to achieve my goal please.

Comment: If my code solves the first problem //Remove time data
    var comDate = sDate.substring(0,sDate.length - 9); 
    $('p.date').html(comDate);

Comment: Ok to finish this post off and to clarify my question. This is the code that I ended up writing which achieved my goals.                   //Remove time data and reformat date
 var comDate = sDate.substring(0,sDate.length - 9); 
 var array = comDate.split('-');
 var year = array[0];
        var month = array[1]; 
        var day = array[2];    $('div.date').html('<span>'+month+'.'+day+'.'+year+'</span>');

Comment: And why do you do that? Date object returns days months and years separately with no string operations. And you can put dots in the string in `toString`